# How to prove the following cone theorem

Tags: convex-analysis, dual-cone

If $K \subset R^n$ and $0 \in K$. Define $K'=\{u|\langle u,x\rangle \leq1, \forall x \in K\}$.   Note: $\langle u,x\rangle = u^Tx$

Prove:

**If $K$ is a cone, then $K' = -K^*$, where $K^*$ is the dual cone of $K$.**

I use contradiction:

If $K' \neq -K^*$, i.e. there exist $y \in K^*$, and $y \notin K'$. That is $x^T(-y) > 1 \to x^Ty < 1$. $\forall x \in K$.

I still cannot find any way to use the cone property to say $K$ is not a cone. Obviously, I get an intersection of halfspace, which is stll a cone.

Any better way to prove this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $u \in K'$.  If $x \in K$, then $cx \in K$ for all $c > 0$,
and so
\begin{align}
& \langle u, cx \rangle \leq 1 \quad \forall c > 0 \\
\implies & \langle u, x \rangle \leq \frac{1}{c} \quad \forall c > 0 \\
\implies & \langle u, x \rangle \leq 0.
\end{align}
Hence, $u \in -K^*$.  This shows that
\begin{equation}
K' \subset -K^*.
\end{equation}

Now suppose that $u \in -K^*$, so $-u \in K^*$.  If $x \in K$, then
\begin{align}
& \langle -u, x \rangle \geq 0 \\
\implies & \langle u, x \rangle \leq 0 \\
\implies & \langle u, x \rangle \leq 1 
\end{align}
which shows that $u \in K'$.
Thus,
\begin{equation}
-K^* \subset K'.
\end{equation}

Putting these pieces together, we see that
\begin{equation}
K' = -K^*.
\end{equation}